# From several table VS inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I can't get the point.

What is the difference between

```
select e.empid
from employee_table e
inner join customer_table c
on deref(c.infos).personid = deref(e.infos).personid
order by e.empid;
```

and

```
select e.empid
from employee_table e, customer_table c
where deref(c.infos).personid = deref(e.infos).personid
order by e.empid;
```

The results are the same.
Is one faster to perform than the other ?

When to use an inner join when we can simply select from multiple table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these two queries are equivalent. But the first one is using ANSI-92 style joins and the second is using ANSI-89 style joins. The newer join syntax is less prone to error and it has been around for 25 years now.

You should always use the ANSI-92 style joins.

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I edited the post for e.supervisor. Thank you for the advice. Does it run exacltly the same in the sql engine ?

Comment: Well I don't know which sql engine but these are ANSI standards and nearly every DBMS follows these pretty close. Certainly on joins all of the major ones will be identical.